# SQL Server process blocked by tempdb

Tags: sql-server

When I tried to perform a query in my SQL Server database it was taking too long. When I opened the resource monitor, I saw the RESOURCE_SEMAPHORE wait type and I saw that the query is being blocked by ProcessID 56. Process ID 56 in my case as you can see from the image below belongs to tempDB. Can someone please explain what could be going here? If I run the query from Nodejs server I get:

```
RequestError: Query timeout expired
```

I resolved the issue by killing process 56. Once I did that and refreshed the process monitor it showed block on some other process which I deleted as well which  resolved the issue. But this has happened a few times now and I just wanted to know what I can do to prevent situations like this in the future.

[image]

Comment: Is this a production system? You can't go killing spids willy nilly! There are numerous system DMVs you can use to find out what the relevant spid is doing, a handy tool to use is [WhoIsActive](http://whoisactive.com/)

Comment: TempDB is used by other databases on the server and is used all the time, and this is completely normal. Your issue is the blocking. You need to find the query that is blocking and see why is blocking and then fix that issue. OR it could be your TempDB is not set up correctly and/or is either too small.

Comment: This is a development system. I do have the prod database copied down though. I never had this issue in production but I am afraid if it is happening in development it can happen in production. Also where can I read about the dangers of deleting spids? I will download the tool as well

Comment: @perry147 thanks for the info. The tempdb size states that it is 16 MB and the space available is 4.60 MB. I did not know that I can see the query which is blocking. All I see is that it is a SELECT command. Do I use the WhoIsActive tool to figure that out?

Comment: 4.60 MB???  There is your issue, TempDB can not grow. And yes you can use Sp_WhoIsActive and the column SQLText and it will show the sql commands running per spid.

Comment: `Database` in that listing just means which database the connection has set. You want to use [`dm_exec_requests` and `dm_exec_sql_text`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-requests-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#a-finding-the-query-text-for-a-running-batch) to get the actual query text which is blocking.